# What is the benefit of Cordova over UIWebView and local HTML?

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

I have a native iOS app that will display HTML content embedded in the app in a web view.  I was going to embed a Cordova/PhoneGap project into my app and use a CDVViewController ([link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html)), but before I got that far, I managed to use a basic UIWebView element to load the content directly.  Here's the code I'm using now:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("www/index", ofType: "html")
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
missionView.delegate = self
missionView.loadRequest(request)
```

I added the "www" directory into my project path, which contains all of the page content.  It loads correctly, runs the local JavaScript content and CSS styling.

So, my question is: Why would I use the overhead of Cordova when this seems to do exactly what I want?  Is it just the integration with native controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood what Cordova is. It isn't about displaying HTML content. It's about having your *whole app* be web-based (just like things were on iOS before there was a way to write native apps in Cocoa).

Comment: Fair enough.  I realize that the main purpose of Cordova is to make full apps using web technologies, not just embed webviews.  My question is about if there's any reason to embed a Cordova project inside of a native app (as described in the link in my original question)?

Comment: Fair enough too! I'd say the link would just be wrong. What you're doing is right.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of the Cordova webview over UIWebView is that you can easily call native functions from javascript code in the webview. You could take advantage of [existing plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) to do this or [write your own](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).

It's not common to embed Cordova within an existing app, but there is a use case and it's a supported feature. You may want to take a look at [this guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html).